# How to generate placebo test for random false treatment?

Tags: regression, stata, treatment-effect, treatment, generalized-did

I would like to do a placebo test to ensure the result of my main staggered DID results. I have a country-level mandate that goes into effect in different years during my sample period, and in some countries, there was no mandate. I examine the effect of this mandate on firms' outcomes in an international sample from 2005 to 2020.

Here is what I would like to do:

- Placebo test by creating an indicator variable randomly by sorting firms randomly and assigning the first $X$ number of firms to treatment based on how many actual $X$ number of firms are treated that year after the placebo indicator is created.
- I would like to run it in regression using `reghdfe`.

Here is an example of my data: note that `magnitude` is my DV and `treatedxmandate` is my IV. `Policy_in_effect` indicates the year in which the mandate is passed.

```
input float(magnitude treatedxmandate) into Year float(country_id firm_id policy_in_effect)
0 0 2009 15 1101 0
0 0 2014 32 2431 0
0 0 2009 45 297 0
0 0 2008 45 297 0
0 0 2010 45 297 0
0 0 2016 50 2872 0
0 0 2015 50 2872 0
0 0 2017 50 2872 0
0 0 2019 50 2872 0
0 0 2016 50 2868 0
0 0 2016 2 9 0
0 0 2017 2 9 0
```